# Selenium WebDriver- if/else statement- isElementPresent- avoid "FAIL" message

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Code (stripped):

```
public void test() {           
    if (isElementPresent(btn) == true) {
        click(btn);
    }           
    else {
        click(btn2);     
    }
}
```

**Console:**

> [ERROR] FAIL: element 'By.xpath: //abc' is not found!

How can I avoid the FAIL message? The test works fine and passes; would like to clean up the output though and not show FAIL when it is passing.

Comment: Your code does not have relation with the stacktrace you provided. Where is that `xpath` used?

Answer (score 0):

Can you put your Xpath code and the html using in your test? If not, we can't help you to solve your problem.